# Importing json into couchdb such that each object becomes a document

Tags: json, curl, import, couchdb, nosql

I have a JSON file in the following format:

```
"rows": [
        {
            "key": [
                null,
                null,
                "dco_test_group",
                "3d3ce6270fdfuashge12e1d41af93179",
                "test_djougou"
            ],
            "value": {
                "lat": "31.538208354844658",
                "long": "91.98762580927113"
            }
        },
        {
            "key": [
                null,
                null,
                "dco_test_group",
                "4cda7jhsadgfs6123hsdaa9069ade2",
                "test_ouake"
            ],
            "value": {
                "lat": "59.696798503352547",
                "long": "11.6626995307082464"
            }
        },
```

I want to import the file such that each object inside `rows` becomes a couchdb document. Right now, I have the following code:

```
curl -X PUT --data-binary @"C:\Users\me\Dropbox (Personal)\Research\Folder\location.json" http://127.0.0.1:5984/db/document_name
```

This adds all the data inside `document_name`.

If I try:

```
curl -X PUT --data-binary @"C:\Users\me\Dropbox (Personal)\Research\Folder\location.json" http://127.0.0.1:5984/db
```

a new db is created but no data gets added. How do I edit the code to get the desired output?

UPDATE 1

Does it matter if all the data is in record? Are there any rules analogous to 5 normal forms of RDB?

Answer (score 4):

Use the bulk-document-api for this. Here is an example from the docs >> https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API#Modify_Multiple_Documents_With_a_Single_Request

```
$ DB="http://127.0.0.1:5984/mydb"
$ curl -H "Content-type:application/json" -d '{"docs":[{"key":"baz","name":"bazzel"},{"key":"bar","name":"barry"}]}' -X POST $DB/_bulk_docs
$ curl -H "Content-type:application/json" -d @your_file.json -X POST $DB/_bulk_docs
```

Note, that all docs are items within a 'docs' array.

Comment: In your response, one has to manually create the json. Is there a way to import the data directly from a json file?

Comment: `$ curl -d @your_file.json -X POST $DB/_bulk_docs` points to a json-file scenario.

Comment: Thanks. It works. We need to add -H "Content-type:application/json" though. Please add that so that I can accept your answer